# Chat app: How to refresh database in background?

Tags: android

I'm working on a chat application, but I have problem with refreshing new messages.
I programmed that when chat screen is opened, all chat messages are fetched from the database and displayed on screen.
Then when user clicks on send button to send new chat message, I reload activity with

```
Intent i= new Intent("com.name.chat");
startActivity(i);
```

so that new message would also be displayed on screen. Now, there are at least two problems with this.

One is that I need to reload whole activity which doesn't look nice, and the second one is that other chat user won't see new message that first user sent to him until he sent his message and his activity reloads.

Is there any way to fix this?

I tried to refresh activity in background every 10 seconds so that at least other user could see messages sent to him without needing to send his own message, but whole screen freezes when I use this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   new Refresh().execute();
   ...
}

    class Refresh extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            while(true) {
            SystemClock.sleep(10000);
            Intent i= new Intent("com.name.chat");
            startActivity(i);
            }

        }

    }
```

I know that solution with refreshing activity every few seconds is not a good solution, but at least other user could see messages sent to him.

How are Viber or WhatsApp created, just the text part without pictures and similar things?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for are customized broadcasts. As described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

There are many possibilities to interact with your broadcast events. So a refresh should be no problem.

But this would not fix your first problem. I think that you should update only your view displaying your messages. Then you do not have to reload the whole thing and you would (depending on your layout's architecture) not accidently delete the text your user types when there is an interrupting refresh caused by your broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have more details about your app structure?
Is it a local network chat application? 
How do the database is populated on the application? (Via a webservice?)
What view does render the chat messages? (a ListView? ...)

**1st idea:**
You could have a Service running in the background, which will be in charge of query the database every n seconds to see if there are any new chat messages. 
Once there are new messages available, the service could notify your activity with a broadcast intent. (as mentioned user2439890)
When your activity receives this broadcast in the `onReceive` callback, it can then update your view which is in charge of displaying the chats messages instead of reloading the whole activity content view.

**2nd idea:**
Supposing you have a ListView displaying your chat messages, you could have it backed by a `CursorAdapter`. Within this adapter you will be able to manage a `Cursor` mapping your database rows with your ListView rows.
Once that is done, you could have a kind of scheduled Timer calling CursorAdapter.onNotifyDatasetChanged() every n seconds to refresh your ListView with possible new database entries.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {

         CursorAdapter.onNotifyDatasetChanged(); // will force the cursor to query the database, and to refresh the ListView with the new chat messages.
      }
    }, 1000, 30000 ); // will be executed every 30 seconds, or whatever you want.
```

**3rd idea:** You can use Google Cloud Messaging API if your polling a remote server.

Comment: I'm using ListView to render the chat messages. For this I've been using tutorial 7. Creating Android Application --> Displaying All Products in ListView (Read), only in all_products.xml I also have editText for new messages and a button. I like your 1st idea. Is there a way to update only ListView and that editText in all_products.xml is not refreshed, since in that case user would lost everything (s)he was writing? And could you tell me how to create that Service running in the background (how to call it, wait for its response...).

Comment: The link for 7. Creating Android Application --> Displaying All Products in ListView (Read) is http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/.

Comment: If 1st idea is too complicated, could you tell me how to create 2nd idea, that only ListView is refreshed every few seconds?